# Make Variable Text Uppercase

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make the text stored in the variable `sendSpecialChat` uppercase, but I can't find out why it doesn't work. This is not actually what I'm trying to do, but I simplified the code:

```js
var sendSpecialChat = hi;  

document.writeIn(sendSpecialChat.toUpperCase());

document.getElementById('print').innerHTML = "sendSpecialChat";
```

```html
<p id="print"></p>
```

Although, it doesn't work. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: `ReferenceError: hi is not defined`, `TypeError: document.writeIn is not a function`. And `"sendSpecialChat"` and `sendSpecialChat` are different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sendSpecialChat.toUpperCase()` will give you an uppercase version of the string. You have a few problems with your code, you need to use quotes(") around strings, but not around variable names.

```js
var sendSpecialChat = "hi";  

document.getElementById('print').innerHTML = sendSpecialChat.toUpperCase();
```

```html
<p id="print"></p>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without putting the `toUpperCase` in the `document.getElementById...`

Comment: Like store the uppercase version in a variable first? `var sendSpecialChatUpper = sendSpecialChat.toUpperCase();` then `...innerHTML = sendSpecialChatUpper;`